# Miller's Theorem - Input Capacitance

Tags: capacitance, input-impedance

Please see attached image. I've become confused if the answer to this question, which uses Miller's Theorem is correct as it should not be a minus, rather it should be a plus. Please see my working out.

Thanks

[image: Question]
[image: Working Out]
[image: Solution]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general case the situations look like this

[image]

Now let as try to find a input resistance.

**Rin = Vin/Iin**

In = (Vin - Vout)/R = (Vin - A*Vin)/R = Vin * (1 - A)/R

**Rin = Vin/Iin = R/(1 - A)**

As you can see we have a "minus" sign. 
We get the "plus" sign only when our amplifier gain is negative (inverting amplify)

**Rin = R/(1 - (-A)) = R/(1+|A|)**

Comment: Okay, so when the gain is negative the resistance would be plus, but when the gain is positive the resistance would be minus? If that made sense

Comment: If you have a inverting amplifier we will have a "plus" sign and our Rin resistance is (1 + |A|) smaller then R or our capacitor is (1 + |A|) larger then C https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_effect. But if our amplifier is "voltage follower"(non-inverting) and your circuit is a source follower (voltage gain from 0 to 1). Now Rin will be 1/(1 -A) times larger. And sometimes we call this a "bootstrap". But for A = 1 we will have Rin = oo. And if A > 1 we have a special case. Rin becomes negative. We create a negative resistor. For example if A = 2 and R = 10 Ohm ---->Rin = -10 Ohm

Comment: And this is how Negative impedance converter work. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_impedance_converter#Basic_circuit_and_analysisWe have a non-inverting amplifier with gain of 2 and a feedback resistor (R3 in wiki) between the input and output terminals.