# Amplification equation for AC coupled Common Emitter stages

Tags: transistors, amplifier, bipolar, equation

Do anyone can tell me how to get amplification equation for this circuit of coupled common emitter amplifier?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fagNOc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

Edit 1

Equation for single transistor only with corresponding circuit.

[image: common emitter amplifier equation]
[image: common emitter amplifier circuit]

Comment: Are you able to analyse a common emitter gain stage with one single transistor only?

Comment: Ok. I understand, you want to check if I'm not just lazy dude. Answer for your question is in _Edit 1_. @LvW Do you can help me now?

Comment: @user19291 No, LvW wants to guide you towards the answer rather than just giving it to you, because that's a much more effective way of learning.

Comment: What's _is best for_ depends on person. In my case best effects are when I can analyze an example. I have some in books and for some I ask around the Internet. I'm not 15yo who ask for doing his homework I want to understood how it works and answer for my question will be *very* helpfull for ME. Thanks

Comment: Try read this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/390192/cannot-predict-closed-loop-gain-of-this-amplifier/390412#390412 Is this help you or not?

Comment: Can you explain what Kf is ?? Also, notice that Ro is now equal to Ro = rbe2||Rc1 and the second stage gain is (beta *Rc2)/rbe2

Comment: Perhaps it helps to know that the ratio (beta/rbe) is identical to the transconductance gm of a bipolar transistor. And gm hasa direct relation to the DC collector current Ic: gm=Ic/Vt (temperature voltage Vt app, 25...26 mV)